# How can I decompile a PowerShell cmdlet?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, clr, decompiler

I have a situation at work where I need to decompile a Powershell cmdlet, possibly to the .net c# code. I found this information ( https://yoursandmyideas.com/2014/12/30/decompiling-powershell-cmdlet-code/ ) but following it, I'm only able to see the function code and not the DLL. The article is about 5 years old, is there a different way to do this with newer versions of Powershell? My end goal is to decompile the dll so I can step through the code and troubleshoot an issue we have in Visual Studio, line by line.

`(Get-Command Get-ServerHealth).DLL` also returns nothing

Below is the function inside of get-serverhealth, an Exchange cmdlet. You see it references other functions that I cannot locate?

- Get-PSImplicitRemotingClientSideParameters
- Get-PSImplicitRemotingSession

The function is:

```
#Name        : Get-ServerHealth
#CommandType : Function
#Definition  :
Function Get-ServerHealth
{
  param(

  [Alias('ea')]
  ${ErrorAction},

  [Alias('vb')]
  [switch]
  ${Verbose},

  [Alias('ov')]
  ${OutVariable},

  [Alias('infa')]
  ${InformationAction},

  [Alias('wv')]
  ${WarningVariable},

  [Alias('db')]
  [switch]
  ${Debug},

  [Alias('pv')]
  ${PipelineVariable},

  ${HealthSet},

  [Alias('ev')]
  ${ErrorVariable},

  [Alias('Server')]
  ${Identity},

  [Alias('ob')]
  ${OutBuffer},

  [Alias('wa')]
  ${WarningAction},

  [switch]
  ${HaImpactingOnly},

  [Alias('iv')]
  ${InformationVariable},

  [switch]
  ${AsJob})

  Begin {
      try 
      {
          $positionalArguments = & $script:NewObject collections.arraylist
          foreach ($parameterName in $PSBoundParameters.BoundPositionally)
          {
              $null = $positionalArguments.Add( $PSBoundParameters[$parameterName] )
              $null = $PSBoundParameters.Remove($parameterName)
          }
          $positionalArguments.AddRange($args)

          $clientSideParameters = Get-PSImplicitRemotingClientSideParameters $PSBoundParameters $True

          $scriptCmd = { & $script:InvokeCommand `
                          @clientSideParameters `
                          -HideComputerName `
                          -Session (Get-PSImplicitRemotingSession -CommandName 'Get-ServerHealth') `
                          -Arg ('Get-ServerHealth', $PSBoundParameters, $positionalArguments) `
                          -Script { param($name, $boundParams, $unboundParams) & $name @boundParams @unboundParams } `
                       }

          $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
          $steppablePipeline.Begin($myInvocation.ExpectingInput, $ExecutionContext)
      } 
      catch 
      {
          throw
      }
  }
  Process 
  {
      try 
      {
          $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
      } 
      catch 
      {
          throw
      }
  }
  End 
  {
    try 
    {
      $steppablePipeline.End()
    } 
    catch 
    {
      throw
    }
  }

                  # .ForwardHelpTargetName Get-ServerHealth
                  # .ForwardHelpCategory Function
                  # .RemoteHelpRunspace PSSession

}
```

Comment: The function is an implicit-remoting wrapper for a command that runs on the server, so you'll have to look for the command there. But what do you hope to get from decompilation?

Comment: The output above was from an Exchange server. Can you be a bit more specific on where to search?

What I'm hoping to gain is the ability to step through the cmdlet code line by line and find out what's failing. The log files are vague.

Comment: I can't help you further, except to say that the function invokes a command (also) named `Get-SeverHealth` on a different computer. Even if you manage to locate the cmdlet binary, I cannot speak to whether your debugging approach is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dnSpy](https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy) to decompile the Powershell Cmdlet.